# Default Authorization role at Controller level and override at method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I'm trying to set default access to the methods on my controller, so I've added the `[Authorize]` attribute on my `ApiController`.

For the most part, unless overridden with the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute this works fine.

Now I want to add another level into the mix. For my authorized methods by default, I want them to require a specific role (such as admin) so I updated the controller level attribute to `[Authorize(roles="admin")]`. For a few exceptions, I don't care what role they are (just being authenticated is good enough).

I thought I could stick with setting the Authorize attribute at the controller level and override it at the individual method level, but this doesn't appear to work the same way as `[AllowAnonymous]` does.

Are there any suggestions out there on how to go about this without having to remember to decorate every new method with the default access level? Something like `[Authorize(roles="*")]`? Even if I needed to have a default role that *every* user was a part of like *AuthenticatedUsers*, that would be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about creating a marker attribute? AllowAnonymous is one such marker, BTW. Create your own Authorize attribute and clear the roles, when marker is there.

```
[MyAuth(Roles = "admin")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [ExemptRoles]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}

public class ExemptRolesAttribute : Attribute { }

public class MyAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<ExemptRolesAttribute>().Any())
            base.Roles = String.Empty;

        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's basically what I'm doing. I've created a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` and overridden the `OnAuthorization` method.

I'm then able to check if the user is is any of the roles tagged in the current custom attribute.
If not, I fall back to default authorization handling.

```
public class InternalAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if(actionContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("actionContext");
        if (AuthorizeRequest(actionContext))
            return;

        // no special authorization found. fall back to base (handles AllowAnonymous, and Controller level attribute)
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }


    private bool AuthorizeRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<InternalAuthorizeAttribute>().Any())
            return false;

        foreach (AuthorizeAttribute attribute in actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AuthorizeAttribute>())
        {
            foreach (var role in attribute.Roles.Split(','))
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(role)) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```